# Blocking method in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to develop a timer for chess game.
There should be a function like

wait for user input there move from **Console**

if wait time > 60

stop waiting and keep going.

What I can think of to solve this is using Thread like:

```
public class Game {
  Thread t1 = new PlayDisc(this);
  Thread t2 = new Timer(this);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}


public class Timer extends Thread{
   Game g;


  public Timer(Game g) {
    this.g = g;
  }

@Override
  public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
      if(i > 6000) {
        g.t1.interrupt();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

public class PlayDisc extends Thread{
  private Game g;

  public PlayDisc(Game g) {
    this.g = g;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = s.nextInt();
    int y = s.nextInt();

    Point p = new Point(x, y);
    cm.nextPoint = p;
    s.close();
  }


}
```

I know this will not work as Scanner.nextInt() is a blocking method. But I'm required to read input from cmd line.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Why shouldn't this work? `Scanner.nextInt()` blocks the scanning thread, yes, but not the timing thread.

Comment: Your threads aren"t started properly. You need to call start(), not run(). Here you're just calling run as a regular method, it won't execute in another thread of execution.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `start()` but the `nextInt()` still blocks the whole program

Comment: What's the `Scanner` scanning from? File? Console? Socket? Pipe? Byte array? String?

Comment: @EJP it's console, thank u for point out that and I've also updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `Scanner` is that you don’t have control over the method’s reading more bytes which can always cause blocking. The safe way is to read from `System.in` manually and create a `Scanner` which can only read the bytes you already got from the console. Then you can do polling (with sleeping) for implementing a time-out. By choosing the right amount of time for sleeping you get the right balance between responsiveness and CPU usage.

The example program below uses a check interval of 200ms which is good enough to be perceived as “immediate response” by a human user. This value is independent from the wait time which you can configure freely (as long as it is significantly higher than the check interval).

Other things to be aware of is that we calculate a deadline at the beginning rather than aggregating waiting times to be independent of CPU usage within the loop. And we use `System.nanoTime()` to be independent from changes that might happen to the system’s clock.

```
long timeOutNS=TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos(1); // 1 min timeout
long checkNS=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(200); // check input every 200ms

int input=0;
boolean hasInput=false;

readWithTimeOut: {
  System.out.println("Enter int: ");
  long deadLine=System.nanoTime() + timeOutNS;
  for(;;) {
    int a = System.in.available();
    if(a>0) {
      byte[] b=new byte[a];
      a=System.in.read(b);
      if(a<=0) break readWithTimeOut;
      Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(b, 0, a));
      if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        input=scanner.nextInt();
        hasInput=true;
        break;
      }
      else if(scanner.hasNext())
        System.err.println("not an int: "+scanner.next()); // consumes token
      continue;
    }
    long remaining=deadLine-System.nanoTime();
    if(remaining<=0) {
      System.err.println("timeout");
      break readWithTimeOut;
    }
    LockSupport.parkNanos(Math.min(remaining, checkNS));
  }
}

System.out.println( hasInput? "entered "+input: "no valid input" );
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a `Timer` class (in fact two of them, `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer`). But as you've realized, the blocking nature of `nextInt()` prevents you from doing anything after the timeout. You would need an additional library that would give you better console control than Java does by default. That, or use `Swing`.

Edit: It might be possible to perform a hack of some sorts, by using a polling loop with `hasNextInt()`. That way you wouldn't let the scanning thread block.

Re-Edit: Nah, it's not possible, since hasNext() will block. You'll have to test whether the interrupt will get you out of the trouble here (it might not).

Comment: How can I use Timer class to solve this. If I schedule a task to interrupt t1, will it not be blocked?

Comment: I know a GUI with listener can handle this perfectly but I'm actually learning Java and asked to do a console program.

Comment: Even without another thread, you could sleep for a second and then poll with `hasNextInt()`. That way you could bypass the blocking completely.

Comment: did some search but still don't get the polling loop thing.Could you please explain more or show some code?

Comment: Simply loop and wait until either the time runs out, or you've got input.

Comment: I might be wrong but isn't it that `hasNextInt()` will check if next input is a Integer but not check if a Integer have been input.

Comment: You should spend more time reading the Javadoc. It will check whether there is input and whether that input is an integer. You could try just `hasNext()` too.

Comment: Doesn’t work that way. Regardless of whether you use `hasNextInt()` or `hasNext()`, both will attempt to read bytes which means both will *block* if the input is the console and there is no input…

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Java's built-in terminal handling is quite shitty.

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream.available()` is a non-blocking method that you can use to check if there's something in the stream.
If you don't care about spinning (and thus wasting a processor core) that's as simple as it can get:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleReadWithTimeout {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {

        int i = readIntWithTimeout(5 * 1000);

        scanner.close();
    }
    // returns -1 in case of timeout
    static private int readIntWithTimeout(long timeoutInMs) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.in.available() == 0) {
            if (timeoutInMs < System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) {
                return -1; // or maybe throw a TimeoutException ?
            }
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```